# Modifying SOAP header prefix (Axis 1.4)

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, apache-axis

I am trying to configure the SOAP Request to consume a web service

Here is the Expected SOAP Request

```
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ABCS/Industry/Telco/ChannelLayer/ProcessPaymentChannelLayerReqABCSImpl" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<env:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" env:mustUnderstand="1">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test123</wsse:Password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</env:Header>
```

I have managed to bring the SOAP request like this.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" env:mustUnderstand="1" soapenv:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next" soapenv:must
Understand="0">
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:Username>test</wsse:Username>
<wsse:password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">test123</wsse:password>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

They are all most same, the only difference is  the prefix of Envelop tag from **soapenv** which is need to be changed as **env**

In the method in which i am trying to configure SOAPRequest, i have access to **org.apache.axis.client.Stub**.

**Note: I tried accessing SOAPEnvelop to set the prefix, it was returning as null :(**

Thanks in advance

Comment: The prefix value doesn't matter. Why do you think you need to change it? If you're having problems processing the request, describe those problems, *don't assume a cause*.

Comment: @kdgregory We are trying to consume a service for which we are not owner, when we triggered a request to consume the service we got the following error
**Error while invoking inbound message handler.
An error has occurred while attempting to invoke the inbound message handler class "class com.collaxa.cube.security.Authenticator" for the message "".  The exception reported was: Could not apply security [Invalid credentials for user test]**
when we tried to investigate the root cause for this exception, they have suggested us to send an identical SOAP request which i have posted in the question.

Comment: I recommend using a tool such as SOAPUI for any such testing. Or you could send the message as a string over a `HttpUrlConnection`.

Comment: But before that, perhaps you should just look closely at the two requests, and see how they're different. Hint: you define an attribute twice in the same element, with different values.

Answer (score 1):

The above two XML snippets are not same, check the following differences:

env:mustUnderstand="1" where as you are sending soapenv:mustUnderstand="0"

Actually your second XML is overriding the mustUnserstand header twice?

Also as @kdgregory mentioned, prefix really doesn't matter just ensure name spaces and header values are correct.